# An inequality for expected value of normally distributed variables

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions

> **Question.** Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be random variables with normal distribution. Is it true that
>   $$\mathbb E \prod_{i=1}^nX_i^{2k}\ge\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb E X_i^{2k}$$for any $k\in\mathbb N$?

(The problem was posed on 22.06.2017 by Ph D students of H.Steinhaus Center of Wroclaw Polytechnica. The promised prize for a solution is "zywa kura", see pages [37,38](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=1&page=37) in the [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka). To get the prize, write to the e-mail: hsc@pwr.edu.pl).

Comment: Who wants a "live hen"?

Comment: you mean that a joint distribution is normal with some covariance matrix? Else it is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem posed above is a semi-well-known open problem that I believe is equivalent to the *real polarization conjecture*. A more general version of the question posed above is offered as Conjecture 4 in [this paper of Wenbo Li](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10959-010-0329-0), who considers arbitrary positive powers of the type $|X_i|^{p_i}$.

For the case $k=1$, a proof is known. Have a look at [Theorem 2.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.0028.pdf) in the linked paper for a proof of $k=1$ case (thanks to **Iosif** for alerting me that my answer was only about the $k=1$ case). In particular, the variables have to be jointly Gaussian with mean zero. Moreover, equality holds if and only if they are independent or at least one of them is a.s. zero.

Comment: That theorem seems to be a rather deep result. However, it seems to cover only the case $k=1$ of the inequality in question. Is there an easy way to extend that theorem to $k\ge2$?

Comment: oh sorry about the rushed claim; the general case for all $k$ is a "well-known" open problem related to the "real polarization conjecture"

Comment: in particular, see section 4 of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10959-010-0329-0 for a formal conjecture slightly more general than the OP.

Comment: Thank you Suvrit for the references. The conjecture in the linked paper, with unequal and arbitrary positive real exponents $\alpha_i$ in place of the constant exponent $2k$ for all $X_i$'s, seems substantially less tractable than even the OP's conjecture.

Comment: You're welcome Iosif. It may indeed be that the variable exponent version is much harder than the $2k$ one (though perhaps more revealing of what is actually going on) --- I'll trust your judgement on this!

Answer (score 7):

Some partial counterexamples:

Let us assume that "with normal distribution" means "with joint normal distribution". Even then, in general the inequality will not hold. Indeed, 
\begin{equation}
 E(Z-1)^2(Z+1)^2<E(Z-1)^2\;E(Z+1)^2, 
\end{equation}
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

The inequality may hold assuming also that the $X_i$'s are zero-mean.

However, the stronger inequality 
\begin{equation}
 E \prod_{i\in S\cup T}X_i^{2k}\ge E \prod_{i\in S}X_i^{2k}\  E \prod_{i\in T}X_i^{2k}
\end{equation}
for finite disjoint sets $S$ and $T$ will not hold 
in general (or even when the set $T$ is a singleton) -- even if the $X_i$'s are zero-mean jointly normal. 
E.g., let $X_1=Z_1$, $X_2=Z_1-Z_2$, $X_3=\frac12 Z_1+Z_2$, where the $Z_i$'s are independent $N(0,1)$. Then 
\begin{equation}
 E X_1^2 X_2^2 X_3^2=\frac{15}4<4\times\frac54=E X_1^2 X_2^2 \ E X_3^2. 
\end{equation}